# Swap Windows 8 Pro / 8.1 licenses?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, license

I had bought a retail copy of Windows 8 Pro for my laptop some time ago and when I built a desktop PC recently, I decided to use a retail copy of Windows 8.1 for it. Since then, the laptop has been updated to Windows 8.1 Pro.

Now, is it possible to use the Pro license on my desktop and the other on my laptop? Is it possible to swap them like that? I'd like to do it before upgrading to Windows 10.

Comment: The Windows 8.1 Core license is tied to your laptop and cannot be transferred to your desktop.  You can format your laptop and install Windows 8.1 Core, if you want, then install the Windows 8.1 Professional on the desktop.

Comment: @Ramhound I thought retail licences allowed transfer to other hardware if removed from previous hardware?

Comment: @Moab - The license I say cannot be moved is the license that came with his PC.

Comment: @Jay (From another thread) You can always [ask it in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) ;)